# Incomplete Implementation and Missing Context for Method Decleration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm new to developing and I'm teaching myself based on tutorials online, and Stanford lectures on iTunesU (I'm only 15).
I'm having two problems with an email form I'm trying to implement into my app. I took a screenshot, here is the link to it: http://tinypic.com/r/2utq05c/5

I've tried everything and just can't seem to get it to work. Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED.
Thank you.

Comment: @bmargulies its the cocoa class language, objective-C, using storyboard.

Comment: Cocoa doesn't support storyboards. If you're using storyboards, you must be using Cocoa Touch.

Comment: @PeterHosey I just checked, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that `@end` line? That ends the class implementation. You can only implement methods within a class implementation—i.e., between the `@implementation` line and its corresponding `@end`.

That isn't the only syntax error in that file. You also haven't finished writing your `email` method, so the method that you have after it is technically within it. Methods can't go within methods, so that's another error. The solution to that one is simply to finish the `email` method.

Comment: okay so i delete the @end line, however i get many parse issues, you're saying I should add it at the end of the email form code, at the end of the implementation?

Comment: @user1350047: You don't want to delete it, because you do need to end the implementation. You just can't end it before the methods that have to be within it; you have to end the implementation *after* the methods.

Comment: So I finish writing my email method, then I end the implementation _there_.

Comment: @user1350047: If you `@end` just after the `email` method, the code will still be broken, because you'll still have a method outside of the implementation (i.e., not between `@implementation` and `@end`).

Comment: I Got It!!!!! Thank you, I understand now, I feel like a noob :) It did however give me another problem that wasn't present before. It's a parse issue with an expected identifier, I'm sure I'll work it out. Thanks once again for all the help!

Comment: @user1350047: Having an expected identifier isn't an error. After all, the compiler expected it. You get an error when you *don't* have an expected identifier—i.e., the compiler expected an identifier in a certain spot and you gave it something else or nothing at all there.

Comment: Once again you're right, I just learnt this using the tutorials, I couldn't however fix the problem, because when I got rid of the the expected identifier (@implementation firstapp.h, the .h) i got like 6 new errors through out the file

Comment: @user1350047: @'implementation must be followed by a class name, not a filename. You should probably have a look through Apple's own Objective-C Primer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

Comment: @user1350047: One other thing: Your use of the header's filename there suggests that you consider the header the primary place where the class is created. It's the other way around, actually: The compiler is invoked for each *implementation* (.m) file, and it's only because you `#import` the header at the top of that file that the compiler sees the header at all. This will become important the first time you have two classes that have to know about each other.

Comment: @implementation classname (named when i first created file right?) : parent class (what is this? is it the base class the language gives to you?)

Comment: @user1350047: You should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Okay, i will, thank you for all the help, i really appreciate it. I'm reading through the Objective-C primer you mentioned earlier, it's really helping me. If I ever do release an app, you'll be mentioned in it :)